# Fancybox v2: Loading animation is not being shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

In my scenario, I'm linking to fairly large images (both in dimensions and filesize). It's understandable that fancybox will have to load for a few seconds before displaying them. The problem is that the loading animation is not showing up, so when the user clicks the thumbnail, it gives the impression that nothing is happening. Fancybox eventually comes up a few seconds later.

There is a secondary issue, also. The images are set to display as a gallery, via the "rel" attribute. Even when the user is viewing one image, browsing to the next takes a while (again, due to filesize), but because the throbber is not showing up, it seems like the prev/next buttons are not working. Any ideas?

I should add that I'm using fancybox v2.

My code (after including the necessary css and scripts for fancybox and the buttons helper, of course): http://pastebin.com/u3g8U8FS

Comment: Are you using the latest (currently v2.0.6)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to the latest version (2.0.6) did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `fancybox_loading.gif` as well as the `fancybox_sprite.png` files are in the same folder as the `jquery.fancybox.css` file

Comment: Yes, I made sure the images were in place. Very odd.